# Jest and Typescript: branch not covered on constructor super ()

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I know exactly that calling `super()` on a constructor will cause a `branch not covered` because how typescript transipile it.
The problem is, how this error is not shown every time?

I have this two class:

```
class VastError extends Error {
    public readonly code: VastErrorCodes;

    constructor(code: VastErrorCodes) {
        super(`Error parsing vast: ${code}`);
        this.code = code;

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, VastError.prototype);
    }
}
```

and

```
class LinearWrapper extends AbstractLinear {
    constructor(element: Element) {
        super(element);
    }
}
```

(I've omitted implementation detail).
In first case coverage report a branch not covered when I call `super(Error parsing vast: ${code});`
For the second class not.

Note that obv typescript transpile them in the same way:

```
function VastError(code) {
    var _this = _super.call(this, \"Error parsing vast: \" + code) || this;
    _this.code = code;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(_this, VastError.prototype);
    return _this;
}
```

and

```
function LinearWrapper(element) {
    var _this = _super.call(this, element) || this;
    return _this;
}
```

Comment: Any news on this? Having the same problem.

Comment: No, sorry. No update on this... ;(

Comment: Found out that creating the coverage report in es6 does the trick.

Comment: ?? You mean transpile ts into es6 and then use babel to transpile es6 to es5?
Or just for tests?
Because in my case for production code I'd like to transpile directly TS to ES5. Ts compiler is way much smarter, as it can avoid unnecessary pieces of code due to types.
For example, check the difference between a class transpiled to es5 code by babel and by ts. ts version is a beautiful old constructor function with methods in prototype...